# Where should I ask a question about what can be asked in a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions

I wanted to ask the question "does firmware qualify as software for softwarerecs.stackexchange.com?" but then I realised I'm not sure where I should ask this question.

So my question is about asking this kind of question - where should I ask it?

softwarerecs.stackexchange.com itself?

meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com?

area51.stackexchange.com?

meta.stackexchange.com (here)?

other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The site's own Meta, [Meta Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/) in this instance, would be the best place to ask questions about the site itself, and the community's rules, guidelines and general expectations.

However, in order to post Meta questions you'll first need to [earn at least 5 reputation points](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) on the main site. If you don't have any rep on the site, but have over 20 rep *network-wide*, you could always try asking [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/12851/software-recommendations). Otherwise, your best resource to find out what questions the site welcomes is its [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).

---

For more details, see: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Ah... so that makes it a bit of a cyclic problem... :) I guess I'll have to ask my question and take the chance of getting downvoted.

Comment: @traveh Well since you have over 20 rep network wide, you could always try asking in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/12851/software-recommendations

Comment: Cheers. I did ask in the chat and got my answer (which is, by the way, that firmware is considered as software).